# Controls change place and form size changes

Tags: vb.net

I have designed a form in VB.NET.  At design time I have placed two buttons on it.
When I run it, the form size looks smaller and the buttons I have placed at the bottom are not visible.  Also the alignment of the text and picture box is also different from what I set at design time.

Computer at which I[image] am running the form is using a different resolution.

Comment: Unusual to see this on the same machine.  Reset the AutoScaleMode property, just in case.  This is otherwise going to require repro code to diagnose the issue.  Post it to a file sharing service.

Comment: This is not on the same machine.  First one is on the machine with normal view and second one on machine with 125% view (LCD)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense then.  Leave AutoScaleMode set to Font to allow the form to adjust itself to the dpi setting.  Don't assign the Size property in your code and don't set the MaximumSize.

Comment: Thnaks Hans !My code displays different Groub Boxes depending on the situation.  I actually make them visible and resizes.  So I should not resize it?

Comment: If you have code that resizes the form then you'll have to do so  carefully.  Only set the ClientSize property (not Size) and be sure to make it at least as large as the control's Bottom and Right properties.  Plus some to create a margin.  Never assume that either the form or the controls have their design time Size and Location.

Answer (score 1):

change the properties (F4) of the buttons: in ANCHOR put Bottom, Right
your buttons will be tied to the bottom and the right of the screen, instead of to the top, left, which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the screen size at runtime with

```
Dim screen as System.Windows.Forms.Screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen
```

and using a scale factor depending on the current size (in design), scale the window to match.  Check the coordinates of the buttons by hand to make sure they are not outside of the visible portion of the window.

You may not have to leave this feature in if you can debug it to the point that you know the exact resolution that you need.